# How to Setup Database and access database in iphone

Tags: iphone, database, ios, installation

I am working on a new project where i want to setup the database and access the values whenever i want.So i don't know how to start this.what library should be used for this.Can any one help me...

Thanks,
Anish

Answer (score 1):

Core Data can be a good way to get some abstraction: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Or, go with SQLite: http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend to use Core Data. You can use SQLIte as the store for your Core Data application. Please refer the apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

You can use [SQLite Manager an Add On of firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). To See the SQLite Store created by Core Data.